# How to get the created company list in Tally?

Tags: .net, xml, api, integration, tally

I am trying to get the all company list from tally through tally API. For that I am using the Tally.dll assembly but once I invoke the GetListOfCompanies() (defined in the Main class of the tally.dll) it's giving me an error message which I have been shared in my attachment.

Please let me know if is there any other approach to get the same or why I am getting the error message?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Said You are using Tally.dll but did not mentioned Source link
How anyone know about that assembly without knowing source

But anyway if you are willing to Change Library I will Suggest [Tally Connector](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector) (if using [.Net Framework](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector/tree/net_framework))
Library which is open-source and developed by me

```
//To initiate instance 

public Tally Ctally = new Tally();

//To get ListofCompanies opened in Tally

List<Company> OpenedCompanies = await Ctally.GetCompaniesList()

//To get companies in Path

List<Company> CompaniesinPath = await Ctally.GetCompaniesListinPath()
```

You are getting that error because you initiated directly Main method instead of initiating Entryclass provided by library

For Ex: in TallyConnector entry class is Tally, so I intiated like this

```
public Tally Ctally = new Tally();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now I am using TallyConnector instead of using Tally.dll but I am getting an error message : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1705 Assembly 'TallyConnector' with identity 'TallyConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,-- I can not change my version is there any other way to achive the same?

Comment: What is the reason behind cannot change version ,because upgrading is good,
Anyway if you don't want to upgrade ,You can downgrade Tally Connector and build

Comment: Hi, Sai thanks for your reply, All stuffs' are working fine but as I have created the one company in the TallyPrime and try to access from the tabllyconnector   List<Company> OpenedCompanies = await Ctally.GetCompaniesList(); not able to get the any list means getting result zero. So is there any security setting?

Comment: Check whether  tally ODBC is server is running & if tally is running other than 9000 port 
then you need to configure using tally.setup()

Comment: I am able to get the details from the function GetCompaniesListinPath() but I am not able to get the company list from Ctally.GetCompaniesList(). If GetCompaniesListinPath is working so why is GetCompaniesListis not working? because same setting should be work for both. Can you please check?

Comment: If settings are correct and GetCompaniesList() return empty list means you didn't opened any company in Tally

Comment: Thanks for reply again. Now I am creating the ledger but again getting some different error like: "No Valid Names!"  and Request XML : 

<ENVELOPE><HEADER><VERSION>1</VERSION><TALLYREQUEST>Import</TALLYREQUEST><TYPE>Data</TYPE><ID>All Masters</ID></HEADER><BODY><DESC><STATICVARIABLES /></DESC><DATA><TALLYMESSAGE><LEDGER NAME="TechNo Computer Ledger 2"><MASTERID p6:nil="true" xmlns:p6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" /><PARENT>Sundry Creditors</PARENT><INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST /><ADDRESS.LIST /></LEDGER></TALLYMESSAGE><COLLECTION /></DATA></BODY></ENVELOPE>

Comment: Its ok, that is a bug in library, Fixed now, 
get latest code by pulling

Comment: thanks for the update, now getting the blank response from api side and also ledger is not created in the Tally.

Comment: Add break point and see what is the response xml received from Tally ?

Comment: checked the same getting blank XML response from Tally

Comment: Post request xml and c# code also

Comment: How do I view a Ledger Account with Voucher Details? which function I will have to call to get the same?

Comment: You want vouchers related to single Ledger?

Comment: Yes, how can I get it?

Comment: https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector/issues/3#issuecomment-868460665

Comment: Hi, sai hope you're doing well.  Can your please share the voucher creation request parameters means what are the parameters required? and how to pass?